# How to set automatically min width of fields by longest text in some group

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I use iReport to create reports, and I would like to know if there is a way to set the width of "optically grouped fields". They should be set to the minimal size that still displays longest text. I have Static Text on left side and Text Field right of them. This Text Fields are set to the width 150 and alignment to right, but I'd like to set smaller size to wipe out white spaces.

Consider some thing like this

```
   Name:            Paul
Surname:         Smither
```

And want automatically to

```
   Name:    Paul
Surname: Smither
```

etc. can be smaller then preset size but no bigger.

Is there a way?? even some component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* change the element width dynamically without using Java frameworks.

The quote from [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf):

> **ELEMENT SIZE**
>
> The width and height attributes are mandatory and represent the size
>   of the report element measured in pixels. Other element stretching
>   settings may instruct the reporting engine to ignore the specified
>   element height. Even in this case, the attributes remain mandatory
>   since even when the height is calculated dynamically, the element will
>   not be smaller than the originally specified height.

You can read [this article](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/stretch/index.html#stretch) for better understanding the mechanism of changing the element size.

Answer (score 0):

If it's genuinely just a couple of fields that come from the same row in the dataset, then you could hack something together.

- Use a monospace font
- Define your maximum field length with a String set to N spaces. For example: 
  $P{MaxLengthString} default value is 10 spaces: `"          "`
- Change your field text from `$F{FirstName}` to this:

  ```
  $P{MaxLengthString}.substring(
    $P{MaxLengthString}.length() + $F{FirstName}.length() - java.lang.Math.max($F{FirstName}.length(), $F{LastName}.length())
  ) + $F{FirstName}
  ```

That is... er... a bit more complex. And it only works with monospace fonts. And I can't believe I really suggested this. Don't do it. (But it ought to work.)